# Excel crashes when editing a filtered list

Tags: excel-2013, filtered-index

I have a large (5000 row by 45 columns) list I import from as a csv from another software package.   It contains reasons that are not always accurate, so I filter by reasons and review comments in another column to correct the reason.   Quite often when I do this, Excel will stop and either crash completely or restart with a recovered file.  I cannot use find and replace as sometimes the reason is correct.  Is this normal behavior for Excel??

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not the expected behavior for Microsoft Excel, I work with huge databases and have not seen this happening. I would suggest you look into your computer specs, specially memory. Can it handle that amount of information? Best of luck.

Comment: I didn't think this was normal behavior.   I have 4GB of RAM and deal with files much larger without crashing.  Hmmm?

Comment: Hi, first try saving the document as a .xls file if that does not do the trick then  try removing any addons and reinstalling them or worst, yet worth a shot, remove and reinstall Microsoft Office. It might help.